# Ion Segments (Tabs) to filter my list of cards by one parameter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am pretty new to Ionic, Angular and Firebase and ran into a problem which I can't solve, even after I read all the threads about it and tried to apply them to my scenario.

Situation: 
I am building an Ionic4 (Angular) app which should list news articles from the web and is using Firebase's Firestore as a backend. Each article has a sender and a receiver, and I am successfully filtering for all one parameter to get only articles which have "me == receiver". 
On client side, in the app, I now want to filter additionally for the parameter whether an article is unread or read.

My goal is to do that with Ionic's segments (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment).

I looked through many threats where some were recommending using pipes while others were saying it can be achieved easier. Any solution I tried  to apply did not work yet.

My HTML "Tab2.html" is the following:

```
<ion-segment>
    <ion-segment-button checked>
        <ion-label>Unread</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button>
        <ion-label>Read</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of articles" >
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
            <img src="/assets/barack-obama.svg">
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
            <h3>Tomas</h3>
            <p>{{item.comment}}</p>
        </ion-label>
        <button ion-button clear icon-only (click)="openModal(item.id)" class="morebutton">
            <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
        </button>

    </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

...

My TS file "Tab2.page.ts" includes:

```
  export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

      articles: any;
      filteredarticles:any;
      articleName: string;

      dataReturned:any;


      constructor(private crudService: CrudService,public modalController: ModalController) { }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.crudService.read_Articles().subscribe(data => {
              this.articles = data.map(e => {
                  return {
                      id: e.payload.doc.id,
                      isEdit: false,
                      Name: e.payload.doc.data()['Name'],
                      title: e.payload.doc.data()['title'],
                      description: e.payload.doc.data()['description'],
                      image: e.payload.doc.data()['image'],
                      comment: e.payload.doc.data()['comment'],
                  };
              })
          });
      }
```

To read, write, update & delete to/from Firestore, I followed a tutorial to keep this in a seperated service. My file "crud-service.ts" has:

```
  read_Articles() {
      return this.firestore.collection('Articles', ref => ref.where("parameter","==","1")).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

which is reading the articles from firestore and filtering for "parameter" now succesfully.

In the App (client), I want to filter for "parameter2"

Expected Result: 
I want to have two tabs (ION segment) in the app, which filters the incoming data for unread/read.

Thank you for so much for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html**

```
<ion-segment>\\ngMOdel helps to Default ur unread 
<ion-segment-button [(ngModel)]="Unreaddata">\\use ngModel ,declare ur ts Unreaddata:any='unread'
    <ion-label>Unread</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button>
    <ion-label>Read</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>
```

**TS**

```
<div [ngSwitch]="Unreaddata">\\read variable
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Unread'">\\read string
write ur unread code here \\display unread data
<\ion-list>
<ion-list *ngSwitchDefault>
write ur unread code here \\display read data
<\ion-list>
<div>
```

Comment: Hi Naveen! THanks for your comment. I didn't quite get it working somehow. But I managed to make it work in a similar way: 
     <ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event.target.value)">
        <ion-segment-button checked value="unread">
          <ion-label>Unread</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="read">
          <ion-label>Read</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>

And in the TS I have a listener to call methods based on the input value. 

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: ionic segment is perfect for ngSwitch u can refer ngswitch u will get more idea